# Adding all libraries and dependencies to AWS lambda for python application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I am building a python application that I am running on AWS Lambda. It uses the following libraries.

```
googleapiclient.discovery 
google.oauth2 
googleapiclient 
 requests
lxml
urllib.request
bs4
```

I've tried to just run the app and as expected I get the error  `Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'googleapiclient`

I've tried to just go into the python/scripts and copying each folder into a separate folder and uploading it into the function but that seems tedious and doesn't really work.

Is there any simpler way of just getting all these libraries in a folder and then uploading them to lambda to work with my main app?

AWS documentation doesn't really help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS solution is [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

> A Lambda layer is a .zip file archive that can contain additional code or data. A layer can contain libraries, a custom runtime, data, or configuration files. Layers promote code sharing and separation of responsibilities so that you can iterate faster on writing business logic.

> You can use layers only with Lambda functions deployed as a .zip file archive. For functions defined as a container image, you package your preferred runtime and all code dependencies when you create the container image. For more information, see Working with Lambda layers and extensions in container images on the AWS Compute Blog.

Answer (score 1):

Are you pretty handy with Docker? I had similar issues as you and ended up just building and uploading my own Docker image to use for Lambda.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

It was pretty straight forward to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` as a Dockerfile command.

Comment: No unfortunately never used docker. I will give it a try though. Thank you